# __iter__ and __getitem__ method in Python

Tags: python

```
class Graph:
    
    def __init__(self, Nodes, is_directed = False):
        self.nodes = Nodes
        self.adj_list = {}
        
        self.is_directed = is_directed

        
        for node in self.nodes:
            self.adj_list[node] = {}
        
            
    def add_edge(self, u, v, w):
        
        self.adj_list[u][v] = w
        
        if not self.is_directed:
            
            self.adj_list[v][u] = w
            
    def __len__(self):
        return len(nodes)
        
    def __getitem__(self,node):
        
        return  self.adj_list[node]
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.adj_list)

    
    def degree(self,node):
        '''Total number of edges coming out a given node'''
        return len(self.adj_list[node])
    
    def print_adj_list(self):
        
        for node in self.nodes:
            print(node, "->", self.adj_list[node])
```

```
all_edges = [

    ("A","B", 5),("A","C", 4),("B","D", 6),("C","D", 8),
    ("C","E", 6),("D","E",7)
]
nodes = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
```

```
graph1 = Graph(nodes)

for u,v,w in all_edges:
    graph1.add_edge(u,v,w)
```

Graph printed:

```
A -> {'B': 5, 'C': 4}
B -> {'A': 5, 'D': 6}
C -> {'A': 4, 'D': 8, 'E': 6}
D -> {'B': 6, 'C': 8, 'E': 7}
E -> {'C': 6, 'D': 7}
```

I am trying to iterate through my class object Graph1 and return the key:value pair inside my nested dictionary.

I access the nodes

```
for vertex in graph1:
    print(vertex)
```

Which returns:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

But once I try and access the values inside the nested dictionary I cannot:

```
for edge, weight in graph1["A"]:
    print("Edge:", edge, "Weight:", weight)
```

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I am trying to return

```
Edge: B
Weight: 5
Edge: C
Weight: 4
```

I believe it has something to do with either my **iter** or **getitem** method.

Comment: What does `print(repr(graph1["A"]))` show?

Comment: Actually, I bet you need to do `for edge, weight in graph1["A"].items():`

Comment: Bingo! Thank you, I feel dumb!

Answer (score 0):

for edge, weight in graph1["A"].items():
print("Edge:", edge, "Weight:", weight)